# Looking for starred emails which have disappeared

Tags: gmail

My starred emails disappeared from the top of my Gmail list and I can’t find them. I looked in trash with no luck. What can I do to find them?

Answer (score 3):

To find all emails with a star use the following search term: **is:starred**

To find only starred items in the inbox: **is:starred in:inbox**

to find them in some other label: **is:starred label:labelname**

Here are hints regarding [searching in spam and trash](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/8872?hl=en&ref_topic=1668965) and other [advanced search hints](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en&ref_topic=1668965)

Answer (score 1):

To find e-mails that are starred, including those in Trash or Spam folder, search using this key phrase in the top search box of your gMail web client.

```
is:starred in:anywhere
```

By the way, this works in the Gmail iOS app too, as far as I know.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. However, it seems to be a duplicate of the already provided answer above. Please use the "edit" button if you would like to improve on an answer instead of writing a totally new answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you changed the inbox view from *Starred first* to something else.

To see if that’s the case, hover over *Inbox*, in the left-side column, and click on the arrow to the right of it (the black square with the white triangle from the picture below).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My starred e-mails disappeared as well, and I also looked for them in trash and they weren't there, used the `is:starred` etc.  I finally decided to try `is:trash`, and lo and behold, there they were. I checked them, moved them to my inbox and they reappeared in my starred e-mails. Hope that works for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that my inbox changed from Important and unread to just Important so I guess my starred emails were being put in the Important instead of the Starred.  When I changed my inbox changed back to Important and unread my Starred section got back all of its emails.

Still not sure why my inbox got changed.

Answer (score 0):

I will put my experience here as I had a similar issue:

My inbox is separated in two:

- Starred messages at the top
- Normal inbox below

Some of my starred conversations would not show in the top section of the inbox (starred message section). Some would.

The only way to have all the conversations display was to either:

- Search for all starred messages with `is:starred`
- Go to the "starred messages" menu hidden in the left column

I however found a workaround: I starred every message in the conversations not showing (not only the last one) and then, it came back to the top section of the inbox, evevn after a page reload or on another browser.